# Join two SSD in one APFS volume

Tags: macos, apfs

I had two physical drives in a Mac mini, now they are SSD as I upgraded the old HDD.

Could two SSD be merged into one virtual drive? Would it better to make a volume group as I’m in Catalina macOS?

My main drive is a 500GB SSD and has Catalina macOS with two volumes system and data.

I want to add a 120GB SSD into the data APFS volume so that it works transparently.

Perhaps I could mount the second drive with the Data Point `mount_apfs /dev/disk1s2` ....

Comment: I edited your question to be clearer.  What you seem to be asking looks the same as this question [APFS container over multiple physical disks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309739/apfs-container-over-multiple-physical-disks) to which the answer appears to be *probably not*.  I would install macOS on the small SSD and use the larger for data.

Comment: Good, but how you manage both physical disk, "Data" could be just "Download folder" or "Document folder" but how you can link in the System to be transparent? Maybe with something like the "Firmlinks"?

Comment: In Catalina *"Macintosh HD - Data"* volume is the non read-only volume.  A volume doesn't have to be on a separate physical disk.  See this Apple page: [About the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650)

Comment: You likely want RAID 0. I'm not aware of any hardware RAID solutions for the Mac Mini, but it might be worth researching. For software RAID, see here: https://reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/74z9mb/apfs_and_software_raid/