# How to create a Fusion drive that is not a Core Storage?

Tags: mojave, fusion-drive, macos

**Edit**

> **I could find a solution** to how recreate a fusion drive and a "Macintosh HD" volume so that OS X can be reinstalled. **I suggest to
> people facing similar issue to simply read the answer** that I posted
> to my own question, which will provide them a **step by step
> procedure**.

---

I need to reinstall MacOS X Mojave on an iMac iMac 27'' 2019 (A2115 EMC 3194).

Because of corrupted fusion data structures, the fusion drive was not visible from the installer, so that I had to reset the SSD and HDD:

- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0` (fully wipes the SSD)
- `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 count=1`  (wipes MBR of HDD)

Above commands made both drives visible from the Disk Utility. (They were previously hidden by the Fusion drive container.)
Then, from the Disk Utility, the two drives were erased and formatted in APFS, with GPT partition scheme.

Strangely, `diskutil resetFusion` detects the logical volumes from the SSD and HDD but is unable to detect the solid state drive as a physical drive. (The order of disks is inverted here, but we see that the disk1 of the SSD is not listed.)

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil resetFusion

Internally-located hardware disk device known to the currently-running macOS:
Rotational                               (disk0)

Volumes exported by partitions or storage systems hosted on the above device:
SSD SM0032L                              (disk3s1)
HDD ST1000DM003                          (disk4s1)

Your computer must have exactly 1 solid-state and 1 rotational disk drive
```

**How to fuse the APFS partitions ?**
Here's the current scheme.

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk4         1000.0 GB  disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         28.0 GB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         27.7 GB    disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +27.7 GB    disk3
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume SSD SM0032L             20.5 KB    disk3s1

/dev/disk4 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1000.0 GB  disk4
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume HDD ST1000DM003         20.5 KB    disk4s1
(...)
```

Should I use logical volume commands, delete the synthetized volumes of disks 3 and 4 and then create from the command line the volume of disk3 according to the original scheme here below?

I know how to use `gpt` commands to show and edit the `gpt` tables.

Here was the original situation:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         1000.0 GB  disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS macOS Base System       2.0 GB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Preboot                 185.9 MB   disk3s2
   2:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.6 MB   disk3s3
   3:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s4
   
(...)
```

Comment: Maybe should I use `diskutil ap createContainer disk0s2,disk1s2` like suggested by klanomath's answer here? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309739/apfs-container-over-multiple-physical-disks .  Is it better to have the SSD as main and the HDD as secondary?

Comment: TBH, I'd just get an external 1TB SSD and run off that. Fusion Drives are double the weakness, and IME they get slower as the volume fills. A USB 3 or TB SSD will be faster.

Comment: I agree, but it is for a customer and the amount of user data is tiny (~5 GB). The use seems casual. Even the small 32GB SSD would suffice. There is always some (small) risk of damages when opening the machine that I prefer to avoid in this case. I found a solution to recreate the fusion drive (see my answer below). The only remaining problem is that the installer does not list the fusion drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found how to create the fusion drive.
To allow the reinstallation of Mac OS X, it is also necessary to create a "Macintosh HD" volume afterwards.

**Here are the steps:**

1. Go in the Disk Utility
2. Erase each of the two drives and select APFS with GPT partitioning scheme
3. Leave the GUI, go in the Terminal and enter `diskutil list`.
4. Delete APFS containers on `disk0s2` and `disk1s2` that the Disk Utility may have created automatically on those partitions. Typically, see if there are containers created for `disk3`, `disk4`, or `disk23`, that point to either `disk0s2` or `disk1s2`. Existing containers are deleted by `diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk0s2` and `diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk1s2`.
5. Create the new container that will be the Fusion drive: `diskutil ap createContainer -main disk0s2 -secondary disk1s2`. (Specifying `-main` and `-secondary` flags is optional.)
6. Not necessary, but if you type `diskutil resetFusion`, this seems having effect of naming your volume as "Fusion drive" in Disk utility.
7. **Important**: Lastly, enter `diskutil ap addVolume disk3 APFS "Macintosh HD"`. If you don't have a "Macintosh HD" volume, the installer of OS X Mojave (or else version) won't see any disk and you won't be able to install the operating system.

What follows was solved thanks to David Anderson's comment.
The procedure here above was updated accordingly:

> <strike>However, **there is still a major bug** that currently
> prevents me reinstalling Mojave: Although the Fusion drive is
> correclty viewed from `diskutil list` in the Terminal, as well as by
> the disk utility, **the Mojave installer doesn't list any drive**
> where to install OS X (i.e. it does not see the fusion
> drive).</strike>

Comment: Why not use `diskutil ap create disk0s2 disk1s2 "Macintosh HD"` in place of `diskutil ap createContainer disk0s2 disk1s2`? Or, use `diskutil ap addVolume disk3 APFS "Macintosh HD"` after entering `diskutil ap createContainer disk0s2 disk1s2`?

Comment: Thank you David, you're the king! Two nights ago, I also had the inspiration that the Mac could be expecting some "Macintosh HD" 'label' to see the fusion drive. So, although the Mac I already had split the fusion and installed the OS on the SSD, I decided to build the fusion drive again. After booting the SSD was disk1 and the HDD disk 0 for this time, so I decided to explicitely specify '-main' and '-secondary', to ensure the SSD comes as main. It was not working if specifying "Macintosh HD" after the two disks. So, I used the second alternative you mentioned. And the install works!

Comment: You should update your answer to explain what worked. Also, you should accept your answer so others know a solution was found. I am not sure if you can do this now or if you will have to wait till later to accept.

Comment: I was updating my answer whilst you commented. Also edited my original post, and could accept my answer. The only thing that I could not do is voting up my answer instead of the original post.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, finally. Saved my mac mini setup. Just one thing, maybe it was a typo, but createContainer command did not take disk0s2, I have to use the disk0 or disk4 only